# Python and or "not" returning boolean value

Tags: python, conditional-statements

Can anyone explain why the first 2 statement not return boolean value?

```
print 1 or 1 # prints 1, isn't this condition and should be returning True 
print 1 and 1 # prints 1, isn't this condition and should be returning True
print not 1 # prints False
```

So `and` `or` is not comparison operator which will return True or False?

Answer (score 1):

From the official reference on Boolean operations ([Python 2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) and [Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)):

1. `x or y`: if `x` is false, then `y`, else `x` (this is a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is `False`)
2. `x and y`: if `x` is false, then `x`, else `y` (this is a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is `True`)
3. `not x`: if `x` is false, then `True`, else `False` (not has a lower priority than non-Boolean operators, so `not a == b` is interpreted as `not (a == b)`, and `a == not b` is a syntax error)